# Proving that $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, proof-writing, proof-verification

Given: $|\sin x| < |x|$, valid for $0<|x|<\frac12\pi$ (EDIT: $\frac12 \pi$ not $\frac1{2\pi}$)

Conclusion: $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x) = 0$, also expressed as $|\sin(x)| < \epsilon$ if $|x|<\delta$

Proof:

$-|x|<\sin(x)<|x|$ and $ |x|<\frac12\pi$ and $-|x|>-\frac12\pi$, so

$-\frac12\pi < -|x| < \sin(x) < |x| < \frac12\pi$, so

$|\sin(x)| < \frac12\pi$ if $|x|<\frac12\pi$ taking $\epsilon=\frac12\pi=\delta$

Proved $\square$

Also, as a side question, can I prove $\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0$ using the basic limit theorems instead of $\epsilon,\delta$ and be as RIGOUROUS ?

Comment: You want to show: For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|\sin x|<\varepsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x|<\delta$. You never do this. Especially “taking $\varepsilon=\frac1{2\pi}$” has no place here.

Comment: @carstenschultz Ohh I was uneasy about this(beginner) as $o.5\pi$ is only one instance of $\epsilon$. Can you tell me the way ??

Comment: If you are allowed to use `|\sin x|<|x|` then the result is an immediate application of the squeeze theorem. Your proof is not valid, I'm afraid, because you have to show that *for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ …*

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct, but it is based on the inequality $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ for $|x|$ "small". *If* you are allowed to use this fact (which is not trivial, indeed), then your proof is rigorous.

Finally, since $\lim_{x \to 0} x =0$ is of course evident, you can deduce that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 = \lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot x = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by for |x| "small" ? My only given is |sin(x)| < |x| for $0<|x|<\frac1{2\pi}$.

Comment: Yes, $1/(2\pi)$ is "small" enough :-)

Comment: The inequality $|\sin x| \leq |x| $ is always true. We can say that $\sin x $ is $x$ for $x$ small enough because of $\sin (x) = x + o(x^2)$

Comment: As Carsten mentioned above isn't $0.5\pi$ only one $\epsilon$.

Comment: The proof, as it stands, is not correct. One has to prove the condition for *all* $\varepsilon>0$, not just for $\varepsilon=\pi/2$. Of course, the work is already done, only the conclusion is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the conclusion that, *given* $\varepsilon>0$, you can choose $\delta=\varepsilon$ is indeed true. No need, and moreover this is not what you should prove, to pick $\varepsilon = \pi/2$.